# Java Global Variables & References

Tags: java, reference, global

Ok so I am trying to solve the Dining Philosophers problem. I have only one question. I have a class Philosopher and another class Chopstick. I want that the class Philosopher to have 5 global Chopsticks. By this I mean that each instance of the class Philosopher has the same 5 Chopsticks: if any instance modifies a chopstick, then this modification should be visible to the others 4 as well. 
One solution for this would be to nest classes, but this is something I would like to avoid. Any ideas ?

A second idea I had has to do with references but I think I am wrong. I was thinking of declaring in the main of my program ( Philosopher is not my main class ) 5 Chopsticks ( or a Chopstick Array, doesn't matter). Then call 5 times the constructor of Philosopher in order to create 5 philosophers. The Philosopher constructor would have a Chopstick Array parameter or 5 Chopsticks parameters and initializes the 5 Chopsticks of each philosopher. Are now the chopsticks of each philosophers linked to the same chopsticks, and hence global ? I hope I explained my problem well enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Yes to your second idea. That's the right way to do it. (That's what dependency injection is about, in short.) Be careful when modifying this array across multiple threads.

Comment: Why not a Factory that creates an array of 5 chop sticks and then only gives out a ref to the array when called again?